# Database synchronization between a new greenfield project database and old projects database

Tags: database, synchronization

I'm thinking about developing a new greenfield app using DDD/TDD/NHibernate with a new database schema reflecting the domain, where changes in the DB would need to be synchronized both ways with the old projects database. The requirement is that both projects will run in parallel, and once the new project starts adding more business value than the old project, the old projects would be shut down.

One approach I have on my mind is to achieve the db synchronization via db triggers. Once you insert/update/delete in new database, the trigger for the table would need to correctly update the old database. The same for changes in the old database, its triggers would need update the new database.

Example:
old project has one table Quote, with columns QuoteId and QuoteVersion. The correct domain model is one Quote object, with many QuoteVersion objects. So the new database would have two tables, Quote and QuoteVersion. So, if you change Quote table in the new DB, the trigger would need to either update all records with that QuoteId in the old DB or the latest version. Next, if you update Quote record in the old DB, again you either update the record in the new DB or it might update it only if the latest version of the Quote in the old DB was updated.

So, there would need to be some logic in the triggers. Those sql statements might be kind of non-trivial. To ensure maintainability, there would need to be thorough tests for triggers (save data in one db, test data in the second db, for different cases).

The question: do you think this trigger idea for db synchronization is viable (not sure yet how to ensure one trigger wont trigger the other database trigger)? Anybody tried that and found out it goes to hell? Do you have a better idea how to fullfil the requirement of sync databases?

Comment: At the of the day we implemented some synchronization prototype via sql server 2008 'change tracking' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and decided not to proceed with this synchronization idea as it was too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial challenge, and I would not really want to use triggers - you've identified a number of concerns yourself, and I would add to this concerns about performance and availability, and the distinct likelihood of horrible infinite loop bugs - trigger in legacy app inserts record into greenfield app, causes trigger to fire in greenfield app to insert record in legacy app, causes trigger to fire in legacy app...

The cleanest option I've seen is based on a messaging system. Every change in the application fires a message, which is handled by a recipient at the receiving end. The recipient can validate the message, and - ideally - forward it to the "normal" code which handles that particular data item.

For example:

- legacy app creates new "quote" record
- legacy app sends a message with a representation of the new "quote"
- message bus forwards message to greenfield app "newQuoteMessageHandler"
- greenfield app "newQuoteMessageHandler" validates data
- greenfield "newQuoteMessageHandler" instantiates "quote" domain entity, and populates it with data
- greenfield domain entity deals with remaining persistence and associated business logic.

Your message handlers should be relatively easy to test - and you can use them to isolate each app from the crazy in the underlying data layer. It also allows you to deal with evolving data schemas in the greenfield app.

Retro-fitting this into the legacy app could be tricky - and may well need to involve triggers to capture data updates, but the logic inside the trigger should be pretty straightforward - "send new message".

Bi-directional sync is hard! You can expect to spend a significant amount of time on getting this up and running, and maintaining it as your greenfield project evolves. If you're working on MS software, it's worth looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.

Comment: I can see one issues with the messaging. The update of the DB wont happen in the same transaction and data might be out of sync until the message is handled. If the handler of the message fails, data will remain out of sync.

Comment: Indeed - but if you want to add distributed transactions and real-time synchronization to the mix, I think your project is unlikely to succeed without investing more time in the synchronization than in the project itself - especially if you have performance and scalability requirements. In practice, the messaging solution adds (at most) seconds, not minutes, of delay. The "if the handler fails" concern is equally true of triggers, but by using the messaging scheme, you can make more intelligent decisions - your error handling code can send en email to the helpdesk, for instance.

Comment: "The "if the handler fails" concern is equally true of triggers". Not really, it the trigger fails, the whole transaction fails. All, or nothing. These fails would basically point out areas which are not covered (good thing). Right now I'm investigating CLR triggers, running C# code to do insert/update/delete logic. So far I was able to resolve "trigger triggers trigger" issue by setting a flag in c# that the other trigger is actually running. I completely agree though that there is a huge risk with the synchronization being more expensive than the project itself.